# MySQL JOIN to get multiple entries from same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of users that has a user id and multiple vehicles assigned to that user.  Each vehicle is an integer value that is equal to a vehicle id in a separate table.  I would like to retrieve the user id and the make and model of each of the vehicles associated with that user.  I can get the user id and the make and model of a single vehicle with the following query:

```
SELECT users.user_id, vehicles.make, vehicles.model
FROM users
JOIN vehicles ON users.vehicle1 = vehicles.vehicle_id
```

I have tried multiple joins, etc.. but I have can not get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited to include table structures:**

I tried to include these as images but I don't have enough posts yet.

Users Table

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbn6e0omn96m41k/users.JPG?dl=0

Vehicles Table

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dpr22c9llbzrf2/vehicles.JPG?dl=0

I need to get the make and model of **ALL** vehicles associated with the user.

Comment: Can you provide what users and vehicles tables look like?

Comment: have a users table, a vehicles table, and a user_has_vehicle table, concept

Comment: No images thanks. Just proper DDLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vthokie11 -- Drew has a good point. Your table structure is not good.
You can refer [here](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/)

I would have had a structure in the following way:
1. **user table:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stacktest`.`user`;
CREATE TABLE  `stacktest`.`user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2.**vehicle table:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stacktest`.`vehicle`;
CREATE TABLE  `stacktest`.`vehicle` (
  `vehicle_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `make` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

3.**user_vehicle table:** (which maintains the relationship between user and vehicles)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stacktest`.`user_vehicle`;
CREATE TABLE  `stacktest`.`user_vehicle` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `FK_user_vehicle_1` (`user_id`),
  KEY `FK_user_vehicle_2` (`vehicle_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_user_vehicle_2` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`vehicle_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_user_vehicle_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And now you need to execute this simple query:

```
SELECT user.user_id, vehicle.make, vehicle.model
FROM user LEFT JOIN user_vehicle on user_vehicle.user_id=user.user_id
LEFT JOIN vehicle on vehicle.vehicle_id=user_vehicle.vehicle_id where user.user_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT users.user_id, vehicles.make, vehicles.model
FROM users, vehicles
WHERE users.vehicle1 = vehicles.vehicle_id

Note: It would be better practice to name the column in the user table vehicle_id so it is clear that it is an id in another table and make it a foreign key.

Comment: This does exactly what the join I included in my question does